# search by any keyword in elasticsearch-php

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I have a file indexed which has a name `'dhiraj chetry'`in name field, now
i want to write a query to search with only 'dhi'keyword?how do i do it?
i tried-

```
    $indexParams = [
        'index' => 'my company',
        'type' => 'interns',
        'body' => [
            'query' =>[
                'match' => [
                    'name' => 'dhi'
                ]
            ]

        ],


    ];
```

it gives

```
Array ( [took] => 3 [timed_out] => [_shards] => Array ( [total] => 5 [successful] => 5 [skipped] => 0 [failed] => 0 ) [hits] => Array ( [total] => 0 [max_score] => [hits] => Array ( ) ) )
```

as result

Comment: in json format the result is                              JSON
took : 3
timed_out : false
_shards
total : 5
successful : 5
skipped : 0
failed : 0
hits
total : 0
max_score : null
hits

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

```
$indexParams = [
    'index' => 'my company',
    'type' => 'interns',
    'body' => [
        'query' =>[
            'term' => [
                'name' => 'dhi'
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

Comment: Thanks ,i used match prefix and that did it